# Play 2.0 vs. Play 1.2.5-RC1 + CRUD + Other Modules

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-1.x

I've been asking and investigating around about the new Play Framework 2.0. It seems like a great tool to create websites with Java. It high quality framework I must say.

However, I notice that there are not modules for the 2.0 version out yet. This is because 2.0 is too new and, according to other stackoverflow user, because of a bug in 2.0.

Moreover, other users suggested 2.0 was a much better framework, and the differences were not minor functionality.

My question is...

Would you give up CRUD and other awesome modules to stick to 2.0 framework?? Why?

Comment: Tough understood by coders (most/all StackOverflow users), the tittle is not really very good to be in it's code-like format (my op). --- You talk about your's or other's opinion on the framework in a way (too vague) it is not really adding anything relevant to what's being asked, for the most part of the text. With a single line being all of the actual question, and to my opinion, it itself being of the kind more appropriate on a forum for discussion (or at last formatted in a way it gave me that impression) (See the FAQ), i can't help but down-vote this until a rewrite is made.

Comment: You are taking it too personal dude.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go for 2.0 because:

1. Play framework 1.2.x WILL be discontinued in some future so it has
   no sense to invest your time if you plan to use it more than once.
2. 2.0 is freshly released and there will be more modules if community (means: me, you and others) will publish them.
3. 2.0 isn't just 'better' it's rather 'better suited for the future'. Some well-known properties from 1.x are still missing, here we can conclude in the same way as in point no. 2.
4. Finally CRUD: this is matter of taste, I found that 1.2.x CRUD is not so comfortable to use for me, especially when I needed to modify it in bigger part. Just I preferred to create custom controllers/views from the scratch to do CRUD-like tasks. In 2.0 approach is similar, but it's even more comfortable as using [Play's forms](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/JavaForms) you can achieve both goals: quite easy views for editing your objects + much greater flexibility.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you for answering. Forms are cool, I got to read 2.0 documentation.